# Inequality $ \frac{2x-5}{x-3} \le 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$ \cfrac{2x-5}{x-3} \le 1$

So what I did:

$2x-5 \le x-3$

$x \le 2 $

But the answer is a $2 \le x \lt 3$

Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{2x-5}{x-3} \le 1$  will imply $2x-5 \le x-3$ only if $x-3>0$

If $x-3<0,\dfrac{2x-5}{x-3} \le 1$ will imply  $2x-5 \ge x-3$

Try

$$\dfrac{2x-5}{x-3}\le1\iff0\ge\dfrac{2x-5}{x-3}-1=\dfrac{x-2}{x-3}$$

If $\dfrac{x-2}{x-3}=0, x=2$

Else $$\dfrac{x-2}{x-3}<0\iff(x-2)(x-3)<0$$

Now if $(x-a)(x-b)<0$ with $a<b$  $$a<x<b$$

Comment: So I have to see when $x-3$ is more than and less than 0?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi, Yes, if you want to follow your method. But the method used in this answer does not require that if you understand the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\dfrac{2x-5}{x-3} \leq 1 \iff \dfrac{2x-5}{x-3}-1 \leq 0 \iff \dfrac{(2x-5)-(x-3)}{x-3} \leq 0 \iff \dfrac{x-2}{x-3} \leq 0.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yea I think I can

Answer (score 2):

Write the homographic function in canonical form first:
$$\frac{2(x-3)+1}{x-3}=2+\frac{1}{x-3}.$$
Hence 
$$\frac{2x-5}{x-3}<1\iff\frac{1}{x-3}\le -1\iff x-3<0\enspace\textbf{and}\enspace x-3\ge-1\iff2\le x<3.$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you cross multiplied. Instead of doing this you need to bring the 1 to the LHS so $\dfrac{2x-5}{x-3}-1\leq 0$. Now you can multiply both sides by $x-3$, however you need to take into account that $x$ can be positive ot negative. You can do this by splitting the solution into two cases: $x-3<0$ and $x-3>0$.

Case number one: $x-3<0 \iff x<3$

Multiplying both sides by $x-3$ gives $(2x-5)-(x-3)\geq 0$ since when you multiply by a negative, you switch the inequality sign. Simplifying this gives $x-2\geq 0 \implies x\geq2 \cap x<3$.

Case number two: $x-3>0 \iff x>3$

You don't need to switch the inequality because $x$ is positive. So $(2x-5) - (x-3) \leq 0 \implies x+2\leq0 \implies x \leq 2 \cap x>3= \emptyset$.

Hence the only solution is $x\geq2 \cap x<3$ which is equivalent to $2\leq x<3$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.I shall take note of this for future questions

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\,\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{{2x - 5 \over x - 3} \leq 1} & \stackrel{x\ \not=\ 3}{\imp}\quad
\pars{2x - 5}\pars{x - 3} \leq \pars{x - 3}^{2}\quad\imp\quad
\pars{x - 3}\pars{x - 2} \leq 0
\\[5mm] &
\imp\quad
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\
\ds{\quad\color{#f00}{2\ \leq\ x\ \color{#000}{<}\ 3}\quad}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{align}

Comment: Why do you times $(x-3)^2$ on both sides?Can you explain it?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi Thanks for your remark. The inequality sign does not reverse when you multiply by a $\displaystyle{\underline{positive\ number}}$. Of course, it's allowed for $\displaystyle{x \not= 3}$ which you have to exclude in the final result. In general, it avoids to consider several cases according tho the $\displaystyle{x - 3}$ sign.

Comment: I see.Thanks for the explanation!So if there's a similar equality like this one,I could do the same thing right?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi You're welcome. It's a nice fact to keep in mind.